# Log File locked By Supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, supervisord

I have a Laravel 5.5 app running with supervisor controlling the queue.
All is good in the respect that message get written to the log, but if I try to delete the log file I get the message `rm: cannot remove ‘storage/logs/laravel-2018-01-08.log’: Text file busy`

If I stop supervisor I can delete the logs.

What is it about supervisor that is blocking the delete, and is there a way around it except stopping supervisor?

Comment: Most likely this is either the `stdout_logfile` or `stderr_logfile` (see [Configuration File](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html)) of one of your processes. As long as the supervised process is running, the log is kept open by supervisor to relay the program's output.

Comment: @Oldskool so there is nothing I can do about it? Will this stop any log rotation?

Comment: No, there is nothing you can do about it. You shouldn't even want to delete or modify an active log file of a supervised process anyway. It contains important output if something were to go wrong. If the file is growing too big, schedule a cronjob that restarts the process every now and then (e.g. daily). This should create a new log file, allowing you to delete the old (obsolete) one.